# Eclipse JUnit testing of outer and nested class tests, @RunWith(Enclosed.class)

Tags: eclipse, junit

I have @Test methods on the outer class as well as on static nested classes.

@RunWith(Enclosed.class) runs all nested test, how can I run those *as well as* tests in the outer, topmost class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Enclosed` does not run the tests in the top level class, only the tests in the static inner classes.

Put your tests into an inner class.

Comment: So, is there no "runner" that can do both, outer and inner?

Comment: No, there isn't one. You can use JUnitCore to run the tests in an inner class (see https://github.com/KentBeck/junit/blob/master/src/test/java/org/junit/tests/experimental/rules/ClassRulesTest.java for examples), but this screws up the counting in Eclipse. Your simplest option is to use another inner class.

Comment: Your answer does not answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

The new JUnit 5 which is under development allows tests in nested inner classes: http://junit.org/junit5/#nested-tests

This will run both the tests and the nested classes. Also, unlike the `Enclosed` JUnit 4 runner, I believe JUnit 5 will run the `@Before` and `@After` methods of the outer class/classes before & after every test from the inner classes too (which makes it possible to write tests in a way similar to the describe/it syntax of [rspec](http://rspec.info/)).

(You can also [use JUnit 4 to run JUnit 5](http://junit.org/junit5/#using-junit-4-to-run-junit-5-tests), before JUnit 5 gets more support from IDEs etc).

There's also a third-party runner called [NestedRunner](https://github.com/NitorCreations/CoreComponents/blob/master/junit-runners/src/main/java/com/nitorcreations/junit/runners/NestedRunner.java), which I believe will also do what you want, but I haven't tried it.